# Combining different bands

Tags: qgis-plugins

[image: resutls of my band combination]I have downloaded Sentinel 2 and Aster images with the SCP in QGIS. When I try to build a raster or create a bandset using different band combinations, the images turn out black. When I look at the single bands, it shows me the correct image, but the moment I combine the different bandwaves, I get a black image. What am I doing wrong? Can someone please give me advice?
I did the histogram cut stretch function, but this did not work.

Comment: Can you include screen shots of what you are seeing as well as any other steps to provide further insight so that we can assist on what you are perhaps doing wrong or provide advice.

Comment: What are the pixel values when you query them with the *Identify Features* tool?

Comment: I get values like Band 1 5.6e-45

Comment: Band 2 -5.334+33; Band 3 -5.337+33.

Comment: I've also tried to zoom in and "stretch to current extent". No success